# PHP - mssql connect through terminal but faild in web

Tags: php, sql-server-2005

im using this script to test my connection from  linux server to mssql engine , my issue is when i apply
[root@localhost html]# php sql.php 
You are connected to the new database on the mssql.

Now when i access sql.php from web its give me error "Warning: mssql_connect(): Unable to connect to server: "

Any clue whats realy happing and why i cant connect through web ,  both server in same local network firewall is off

```
?php

$myServer = "mssql"; // host/instance_name
$myUser = "sa"; // username
$myPass = "mypasswd"; // paasword
$myDB = "new"; // database name

 // connection to the database
$dbhandle = mssql_connect($myServer, $myUser, $myPass)
 or die("Couldnt connect to SQL Server on $myServer");

// select a database to work with
 $selected = mssql_select_db($myDB, $dbhandle)
 or die("Couldn.t open database $myDB");

    echo "You are connected to the " . $myDB . " database on the " . $myServer . ".";

      // close the connection
        mssql_close($dbhandle);
     ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

PHP normally runs two php.ini files, 1 for cli and 1 for Apache, you need to make sure your mssql extension is enabled in both, not just the cli one

```
extension=php_mssql.dll
```

or

```
extension=php_mssql.so
```

I'm not sure of the precise module name you need to enable

Comment: php -m output is the output from the command line though, not apache.

Put a dummy file in the webroot and do <?php phpinfo(); ?> this should show you whether or not the extension is loaded through the web php.ini

Comment: mssql extension is loaded in phpinfo page !

Comment: I'm out of ideas then I'm afraid as it's a php/mssql error rather than your die kicking in

Answer (score 0):

I've got similar problem and this is my sollution :) :

while checkig status of httpd "serive httpd status -l"

gru 01 08:58:27 pc6.home python[123130]: SELinux is preventing /usr/sbin/httpd from name_connect access on the **tcp_socket port 1433**.

```
   *****  Plugin catchall_boolean (47.5 confidence) suggests   ******************

   If you want to allow httpd to can network connect
   Then you must tell SELinux about this by enabling the 'httpd_can_network_connect' boolean.
   You can read 'None' man page for more details.
   Do
   setsebool -P httpd_can_network_connect 1
```

And JUST executing command **setsebool -P httpd_can_network_connect 1** fix all problems with connecting to mssql